# how to convert a string passed in a constructor to Uri?

Tags: uri

i have a piece of code in C#. I am using a string as parameter in the constructor to give the filepath then I want to convert it into Uri to interact with the rest of the code in a different class.
How can i do that? Can anyone tell the syntax?

```
    public string m_DTBook_FilePath;
    public DTBooktoXukConversion(string bookfile)
    {
        m_DTBook_FilePath = bookfile;
        Uri uri = new Uri(m_DTBook_FilePath);
    }
```

Whats wrong in this syntax?

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with that syntax. What's going wrong when you try it?

Note that in the snippet you've given, you don't *do* anything with the Uri after constructing it - if the problem is that later you're trying to use `m_DTBook_FilePath` as a `Uri`, then you should actually have:

```
public Uri m_DTBook_FilePath;
public DTBooktoXukConversion(string bookfile)
{
    m_DTBook_FilePath = new Uri(bookfile);
}
```

(I would *strongly* recommend against having a public field in your real code, by the way.)

Comment: There wasnt error.i just wanted to confirm.i adopt ur method, and do this:
switch (m_DTBook_FilePath)
{case "*.opf":
  el();
  break;
case "*.xml":
tr();
break;}
In switch field error is:A value of integral type expected.
In case field, error is: cannot convert implicitly string to uri